# Module Pattern Javascript

Tags: javascript

Não sei se estou aplicando o conceito de javascript modular corretamente, portanto preciso de ajuda!

Eu separei os arquivos `js` por responsabilidades.

Cada arquivo será encarregado para uma determinada função.

Estou carregando estes arquivos da seguinte forma:

```html
<html>

  <head>
  </head>

  <body>
    <div id="app-info">
       <span id="app-name">name</span>
    </div>

    <script src="controllers/controllerExample.js"></script>
    <script src="resources/ajaxApp.js"></script>
    <script src="models/modelExample.js"></script>
    <script src="app.js"></script>
  </body>

</html>
```

**observação**: Eu não quero ir para o `requiresJS`. sem que antes eu tenha entendido como realmente funciona o `modular pattern`

Além disso, eu quero que o retorno do ajax seja atribuído à um objeto global, podemos chama-lo de `ObjectApplication` para que em qualquer lugar da aplicação eu possa acessa-lo ?

Como posso fazer isto ?

Então tenho alguns arquivos js.

- app.js
- controllers / controllerExample.js
- models / modelExample.js
- resources / ajaxApp.js

**app.js**

```
let ObjectApplication = {};
;(function( window, document, undefined ) {
  'use strict';

  function app() {
    var $private = {};
    var $public = {};

    $private.privateVar = 'private var';

    $public.publicMethod = function() {
      return 'Init';
    };

    $private.privateMethod = function() {
      return 'Private method';
    };

    return $public;
  }

  window.Module = window.Module || {};
  window.Module.app = app();
})( window, document );

Module.controllerExample.publicMethod();
console.log(objectApplication.name);
```

**controllerExample.js**

```
;(function( window, document, undefined ) {
  'use strict';

  function controllerExample() {
    var $private = {};
    var $public = {};

    $private.privateVar = 'private var';

    $public.publicMethod = function() {
        return Module.modelExample.publicMethod();
      //return 'Init';
    };

    $private.privateMethod = function() {
      return 'Private method';
    };

    return $public;
  }

  window.Module = window.Module || {};
  window.Module.controllerExample = controllerExample();
})( window, document );
```

**modelExample.js**

```
;(function( window, document, undefined ) {
  'use strict';

  function modelExample() {
    var $private = {};
    var $public = {};

    $private.privateVar = 'private var';

    $public.publicMethod = function() {
        buildAppInfo();
      //return 'Init in Model';
    };

    $private.privateMethod = function() {
      return 'Private method';
    };

    return $public;
  }

  window.Module = window.Module || {};
  window.Module.modelExample = modelExample();
})( window, document );
```

**ajax**

```
let buildAppInfo = () => {
    let url = 'app.json';   
    let xhr = new XMLHttpRequest(); 
    xhr.open('GET', url, true);

    xhr.onreadystatechange = function() {
        if (xhr.readyState == 4) {
            if (xhr.status = 200)
                ObjectApplication = JSON.parse(xhr.responseText);
        }
    }
    xhr.send();
};
```

Comment: Esse código você escreveu ou está adaptando? O nome do tal objeto global está incoerente, tem trechos em que você usa `ObjectApplication` e outros com `MyGlobalObject`.

Comment: @bfavaretto, voce pode considerar o nome de `MyGlobalObject` com `Module`.

O importante para mim, é definir um valor para `ObjectApplication` e acessar os seus atributos em qualquer lugar da aplicação.

Comment: Não entendi a dúvida. E você precisa usar o mesmo nome para esse objeto global em todos os lugares isso deve bastar (porém não analisei os detalhes do código)

Comment: vaja no inicio de `app.js` contem um objeto declado `let ObjectApplication = {};`
e no retorno do ajax, eu atribuo valores ao `ObjectApplication`.

Quando eu tento acessar o `objectoApplication.name` por exemplo, simplesmente aparece `unidefined`, ou se eu acessar o `objectApplication` somente, me aparece `{}`.

O que aconteceu com o retorno do ajax ?

Comment: @bfavaretto, amigo, por favor! reabra a questão, como posso tirar minhas dúvidas se eu abro uma questão e esta é fechada ???

Releia a pergunta e verás que faz sentido a minha pergunta.
Estou falando sobre `Module Pattern`, e só preciso entender como acessar os valores de um objeto apos a chamada do ajax

Comment: É que sua dúvida não está nem um pouco clara, e a pergunta não pode ser reaberta enquanto não estiver clara. Olhando seu código, você está fazendo uso incoerente dos nomes das variáveis, esse parece ser o problema. A resposta do ajax está sendo guardada numa variável global `app` que não existe no resto do seu código...

Comment: @bfavaretto, desculpa a questão de nomes. Já ajustei a pergunta. Então acredito que esteja clara o suficiente agora!

Comment: Bom, o que está ficando claro é que você não entendeu o código de exemplo.Essa sua versão agora deve logar exatamente o retorno do ajax. A variável global que ele cria se chama `Module` (ou `window.Module`, dá na mesma). Não tem por que você criar outra, o que esse código indica é que tudo que for global deve ficar pendurado em `window.Module`.

Comment: Utilizando o próprio console do navegador, veja o resultado https://imgur.com/f9Ac6Wg

Só não entendo porque utilizando console.log(diretamente do arquivo app.js) eu recebo o objeto vazio, mas utilizando diretamente no navegador eu consigo acessar os atributos do objeto normalmente

Comment: Ah, você está falando do primeiro console.log, não do que está dentro do retorno do ajax... É porque a operação ajax é assíncrona, e no momento que o código tenta logar o resultado ainda não chegou. Quando você tenta manualmente o resultado já chegou.

Comment: Certo, e pode me indicar como receber o retorno do ajax ? Sei que existe forma de não alterar a requisição para síncrona.

Comment: Olha, já estamos nos estendendo aqui e não é o espaço para isso. Recomendo estudar uma coisa de cada vez. Se está estudando o module pattern, foque nisso, sem ajax. Sobre essa nova dúvida, pesquise sobre assincronismo, callbacks e promises em javascript.